# On the equation $x^3 + y^3 = z^4$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any rational numbers $x, y, z$ with $xyz \neq 0$ and coprime numerators such that $x^3 +y^3 = z^4$ ?

Comment: $x=1/8$, $y=1/8$ and $z=1/4$? Or $x=1/9$, $y=2/9$ and $z=1/3$?

Comment: Also $(x,y,z)=(17/56, 37/56, 3/4)$ looks nice... There are plenty of them...

Comment: I believe this is a rational surface and has rational parametrization.

Comment: Parameterization is easy to find. It is sufficient to solve the equation. $x^3+y^3=z^2$ Using these solutions. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048734____2
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046719___
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046717_
 Then solve another equation when z is a square.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a rational surface.

One easy parametrization is
$x=s^4 + s\; t^3$, $y=s^3\;t + t^4$ and $z=s^3 + t^3$. From this you should be able to find as many examples as you like.

Comment: Thanks ! Any other parametrization besides yours ?

Comment: But how did you arrive at your answer ? May you also see https://mathoverflow.net/q/371113/123305,

Comment: Note that this parametrization doesn't only find infinitely many rational solutions, it actually finds *all* solutions. Here's why. It obviously gives $(0,0,0)$ by taking $s=t=0$. Now suppose that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution with $xyz\ne0$. Then take $s=x/z$ and $t=y/z$, and you'll get an $(s,t)$ pair such that when you plug them into Nullhomologous' formulas, you get back the original $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^3+y^3=z^4$  ----$(1)$

In the solution given by @Nulhomologous,

if we put $(s,t)=(2,1)$ we get:

$9^3+18^3=9^4$

Where the integer 'nine' is a common factor.

Eqn.(1) has another parametrization & is shown below:

$(2w(p^4+1))^3+(2w(p^4-1))^3=(2wp)^4$

Where, $w=(p^8+3)$

For, $p=2$, we get:

$8806^3+7770^3=1036^4$

Comment: This is just a special case of nullhomologous' solution, with $s$ and $t$ taken to be $(p^4 + 1)/p$ and $(p^4 - 1)/p$.

Comment: @Joe Silverman. Your comment about solution given by "Nullomolgous"  being a general solution is incorrect because his equation does not  produce the numerical solution, (x,y,z)=((17/56),(37/56),(3/4)). Also [z=3/4] in the equation cannot be represented as sum of two rational cubes.

Comment: Regarding the previous comment: for the (x,y,z) solution you have listed, defining s=x/z = 17/42 and t= y/z = 37/42 one can check that s^4+st^3 = 17/56 and t^4+s^3t= 37/56 and s^3+t^3 = 3/4. So it is incorrect to claim that @Nulhomologous's formula does not produce the given numerical solution.

Comment: I only used explicit numbers to be concrete. It is actually a direct consequence of basic algebra that if x^3+y^3=z^4 with z non-zero, and one then defines s and t as in Joe Silverman's comment, then s(s^3+t^3)=x, t(s^3+t^3)=y and s^3+t^3 = z

Comment: @Yemon Choi. You are correct. The numerical solution given by "Nullomolgous" does satisfy the equation. Also his equation look's like a general solution just as "Joe Silverman" commented. I was surprised that the equation is not primitive & has a common factor. Usually a general solutions do not have a common factor like the pythagoras equation of second degree. Namely the general solution, [(m^2+n^2),(m^2-n^2),(2mn)].